C++ Compiler error : The term 'make' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet
I want to compile cpp project in vscode and I write "make to terminal after that I have a error :enter image description here What do you think about this error .How  I solve this?
I can't compile even printf cpp files.Thank you.

If you installed VS Code as described in the official documentation, you have MSYS2. Open a MSYS2 terminal and type in pacman -S make or pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-make. to install make.

First, please do not post pictures of text. Rather, post the text as part of the question. That having been said, it appears that the make program is not properly installed on your Windows box.

If it comes back and says it's already installed, then make isn't accessible in the path and you'll have to add it or use the full path to make.

If you follow the official install guide for VSCode it installs make (and this year's version of gcc).

It's because you don't have make installed on your computer. To install it, follow these steps:

Open UCRT64 present in MSYS2 and enter the following command:

pacman -S make


Now look for the MSYS2 installation location and open the usr\bin folder
Save the directory and place it in the environment variables
Reset cmd

And ready to use :)

Be very careful when putting the MSYS folders in the system path as this puts you on the highway to DLL Hell and related maladies. There are a lot of tools out there using the same libraries and infrastructure as MSYS2 and if one of these other tools gets into the path before MSYS2's stuff, weird and nigh-inexplicable things can happen with your programs if the versions don't match. Or MSYS2 is found before the other tool when running the other tools, making them suddenly seem to break. Carefully curate what goes into the path.
